# filter or subset list by partial object name in R

Tags: r

I have a list with 417 data frames in it. Each data frame has a separate name in the list beginning with "Dec 1981" and ending with "Aug 2016". The objects are in chronological order.

I would like to subset or filter this list just by month name. For example, create a new list object with just the Jan objects(data frames). The name of my list is `SST_list` and I've attempted a few different solution so far. None of which work.

```
Jan_data <- SST_list[names(SST_list)=="Jan"]
```

That returns nothing, but is to be expected. I have attempted some code with grep and grepl, but those crash my R session.

I also tried

```
Jan_data <- lapply(SST_list, "[","Jan")
```

but no luck there.

This seems like it should be a simple task, but I'm having quite a bit of trouble.

Comment: Could you show a small reproducible example.

Comment: Someone actually posted the solution and then deleted it for some reason. I will add it to my post.

Comment: It worked perfectly, could you post it again? No partial names in my list.

Comment: Ok, undeleted it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can use `grep` to match the "Jan" substring in the `names` of 'SST_list'

```
SST_list[grep("Jan", names(SST_list))]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - is there a way to do this with purrr functions, such as pluck() and/or keep()? That is, to select elements in a list based on substrings of the elements' names?

Comment: @DSH You can use  `keep(SST_list, str_detect(names(SST_list), 'Jan'))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun - I thought `keep()` was the answer, but I couldn't get it to work. As usual, you have the solution!